# python/pygame, pass input from a class to another class

Tags: python, oop, class, pygame

there is a way to pass a value or a variable from a class to another class without having to pass through  the main function

I'm using python

Comment: You rarely pass data from class to class.  You usually pass data from object to object.  One object can have a reference to another object.  Can you provide a **small** code sample that shows what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

well, of course you can access other objects attributes in methods of a specific object. e.g:

```
class A(object):
    def method(self, other):
         other.somevar = 5

class B(object):
    pass

def main():
    a = A()
    b = B()

    b.somevar = "Hello World"
    a.method(b)
    print(b.somevar) # now prints '5'
```